# AWS CloudFormation, Stack update isn't modifying my EC2 configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to make sure my CloudFormation creates a stack that can be modified using Update or ChangeSets. I realise I have to use cfn-hup and init scripts to achieve this, and what I have seems to work with updating the SecurityGroups in my CloudFormation file, but it doesn't change the actual webserver infrastructure at all. I thought i'd be able to add/remove packages or update configuration files and those changes would be reflected.

Is this not possible? (Im using Amazon Linux 2)

Here is my file. I feel like this should be updating the nginx config file if it ever changes?

From what I can tell reading the AWS docs using `services.sysvinit.nginx.files` should then keep track of my nginx config that is listed, and reload nginx after the migration if a change is detected. It should also be updating the nginx file with any new change to the `server {}` block that I have.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:

  VPC:
    Description: "ID of VPC"
    Type: String

  AMI:
    Description: "ID of base image"
    Type: String

  KeyName:
    Description: "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance"
    Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."

  InstanceType:
    Description: "Amazon Instance Type"
    Default: t2.micro
    Type: String

  SSHLocation:
    Description: "IP address range that can be used to SSH to EC2 Instance"
    Type: String
    MinLength: 9
    MaxLength: 18
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0

Resources:

  ApiEc2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          InstallAndRun:
            - Configure
            - Install

        # install packages and setup files
        Install:
          packages:
            yum:
              php: []
              php-fpm: []
              php-mbstring: []
              php-bcmath: []
              php-pdo: []
              nginx: []

          files:
            /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                server {
                  listen 80;

                  root /var/www/html;

                  index index.php index.html index.htm;

                  gzip on;
                  gzip_vary off;
                  gzip_proxied static;
                  gzip_comp_level 6;
                  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
                  gzip_http_version 1.1;
                  gzip_types text/plain application/json;

                  charset utf-8;

                  location / {
                      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                  }

                  location ~ \.php$ {
                      try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                      fastcgi_index index.php;
                      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                      include fastcgi_params;
                  }
                }

            /etc/php.d/default.ini:
              content: !Sub |
                display_errors = On

            /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                [main]
                stack=${AWS::StackId}
                region=${AWS::Region}
                verbose=1
                interval=5
              mode: 000400
              owner: root
              group: root

            /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                triggers=post.update
                path=Resources.ApiEc2Instance.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ApiEc2Instance --configsets InstallAndRun --region ${AWS::Region}
                runas=root
              mode: 000400
              owner: root
              group: root

          services:
            sysvinit:
              nginx:
                enabled: true
                ensureRunning: true
                files:
                  - /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
              cfn-hup:
                enabled: true
                ensureRunning: true
                files:
                  - /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf
                  - /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf

        # configure any separate execution scripts
        Configure:
          commands:
            01_update_php:
              command: "amazon-linux-extras enable php7.4 nginx1 ansible2"
              test: "! grep -Fxq '[amzn2extra-php7.4]' /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn2-extras.repo"

    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref "AMI"
      InstanceType: !Ref "InstanceType"
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref ApiSSHSecurityGroup
        - !Ref ApiWebSecurityGroup
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: "API Sandbox"
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap

          # Install the files and packages from the metadata
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v \
            --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
            --resource ApiEc2Instance \
            --configsets InstallAndRun \
            --region ${AWS::Region}

          # Signal the status from cfn-init
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? \
            --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
            --resource ApiEc2Instance \
            --region ${AWS::Region}

          #
          service nginx reload
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT5M

  ApiSSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: API SSH Admins
      GroupDescription: Enable public access via port 22
      VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: !Ref "SSHLocation"

  ApiWebSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: API Public Web
      GroupDescription: Enable public web access via multiple ports
      VpcId: !Ref "VPC"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: An example of what im trying to achieve would be to change the gzip line from `gzip off` to `gzip on` and upload the new config yaml as a ChangeSet and execute it on the stack to modify my nginx configuration and turn gzip on

Comment: Have you checked any logs? There should be in /var/log for hup and userdata.

Comment: Also what ami are you using? Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: Hi yep, I checked the logs. Everything for initial creation was great, but the ChangeSet execution made no changes to the logs. I checked `cfn-init.log` and `cloud-init-output.log` and `cloud-init.log`. Nothing changes. Not even if I add/remove a new package from the packages.yum section.

Comment: ChangeSet will not detect any changes in cfn-init. You have to try actually updating the stack.

Comment: HI Marcin. Yes I did do that. I created the ChangeSet then Executed it. It does update the stack, I made some changes to the Security Groups that were successful when I Executed the ChangeSet after reviewing it. However the EC2 changes did not happen.

Comment: hup must be failing or incorrectly setup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228655/discussion-between-simonw16-and-marcin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the chat discussion.

`hup` takes **15 minutes** by [default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html#cfn-hup-hook-file) to refresh. Thus the issue was cause by not-waiting this time as it seemed that `hup` was failing or doing nothing for the 15 minutes.

The time can be adjusted using `interval` variable as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html#cfn-hup-hook-file).

Comment: Thank you @Marcin. The 15 minute interval was integral to figuring out the issue. Seems the config always worked, I just didn't wait to see cfn-hup run as I didn't know about this refresh. Marked as complete!